# Why my gitlab runner can't get access to docker engine?

Tags: docker

I installed gitlab runner via docker and setup to my project, but when I'm trying to build my project gitlab runner can't get access to docker.sock
[here is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLk6x.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your Docker socket to your container with a volume:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock [your-image]
```

Comment: I run my gitlab runner with command from gitlab tutorial 
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#install-the-docker-image-and-start-the-container